# jQuery/Firefox strange thing adding .html to selector (minimal example included)

Tags: jquery, firefox, selector

Hy there

I have a strange Problem with firefox and i havnt found any solution that helps. Below you can find a minimal example of that. 
The code is working with chrome perfectly but firefox would not add any "html" strings to the second div (div.container#c2). I dont know why - does anyone of you has had some problems like this? It would be great if someone could give me a hint.

Greetings Reto

```
<html>
  <!-- Minimal example: firefox selector problem -->
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    div.container { max-width: 300px; min-height: 100px; }
    #c1 { background-color: gray; }
    #c2 { background-color: yellow; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
    for(i=1;i<=2;i++) {
      var target="body > div.container#c"+i+" > span";
      $(target+"#foo1").html("foo 1 is "+i); 
      $(target+"#foo2").html("foo 2 is "+i); 
      $(target+"#foo3").html("foo 3 is "+i); 
    } // End of for while
  }); // End of document.ready
  </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container" id="c1">
    <span id="foo1"></span><br>
    <span id="foo2"></span><br>
    <span id="foo3"></span><br>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="c2">
    <span id="foo1"></span><br>
    <span id="foo2"></span><br>
    <span id="foo3"></span><br>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What Firefox version are you testing in, exactly?  I just spot-checked the behavior in a current build, Firefox 4, and Firefox 3.6 and they all show things fine inside the second container, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`id` attributes **have to be** unique. Replace `id="foo1"` etc with `class="foo1"` etc. Then replace `#` with a dot, `.` (class selector).

Instead of hardcoding the element IDs, you can also attach appropariate class names to the elements, and loop through each element, to eliminate code repetition.

```
  $(document).ready( function() {
      $('.container').each(function(i) {
          $(this).children('span').each(function(j) {
              $(this).html('foo' + j + ' is ' + i);
          });
      }); // End of main loop
  }); // End of document.ready
```

HTML (removed unnecessary attributes):

```
  <div class="container">
    <span></span><br>
    <span></span><br>
    <span></span><br>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <span></span><br>
    <span></span><br>
    <span></span><br>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks man! That seems to work. I didnt noticed that with the id (never had this strange problems). But why does it work in google chrome? :) I'll fix it your way ... thanks a lot. After 3h of debugging your solution is as worthwile as gold *g*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that you're using the same ID for more than one element, which isn't valid HTML. You'll need to use unique IDs (or switch to using classes) in order to correctly identify the elements.

Comment: I'll also thank you for the solution. As read above i didnt noticed that until today. Thank you for your help and have a nice day!